# Create a new record in Dynamics 365 Connected Field Service using Azure LogicApps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub, dynamics-365

I am trying to create a new record in Dynamics 365 Connected Field Service. I have created a query in Stream Analytics which sends the device data to a queue.

In Azure LogicApps the payload message for example looks like this

```
{"Device":"ESP8266","AccValue":21168,"Location":"$GPRMC ..."}
```

This message is parsed using parseJSON so that I can extract each field from the payload. In the next function create new record I can simply use the AccValue and Location for the column Description. However when I try to set the Device parameter as Device, I get this error:

```
{

"status":
400,


"message":
"An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'msdyn_Device'; however, a 'StartArray'
 node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ValidateExpandedNestedResourceInfoPropertyValue(IJsonReader jsonReader, Nullable`1 isCollection,
 String propertyName)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadPropertyWithValue(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState, String propertyName, Boolean isDeltaResourceSet)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ReadResourceContent>b__0(PropertyParsingResult
 propertyParsingResult, String propertyName)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action`2 handleProperty)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadResourceContent(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState
 resourceState)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.StartReadingResource()\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementationSynchronously(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()\r\n
 at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataReaderExtensions.ReadResourceOrResourceSet(ODataReader reader)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader
 messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)",


"source":
"x.crm4.dynamics.com",

"errors": [],

"debugInfo":
"clientRequestId: 03d448c2-e6fe-4bac-b6c4-19328bc2b1bb"

}
```

If I leave out the 'Device' parameter the IoT alert is listed in D365 CFS:

The device with its information is supposed to be newly created as a record with GPS and AccValue for column "description" and device name (ESP8266) for the column "Device" in the Dynamics 365 Connected Field Service. It is already registered with the IoT Hub and sends data correctly.

What could be a solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you have a navigation property (relationship) in CDS and are trying to send a primitive value to it (an int, a string, etc.). It expects an entity or array-of-entity.

You’ll need to cross-check the property values in the payload that you are sending against their corresponding definitions. One or more of the properties being sent is for a relationship and has an incorrect value.

"message":
"An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'msdyn_Device'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.\r\n at